# server log analysis of 404s

Tags: file, logging, googlebot

A large site I am working with is getting 80K+ 404s a day from Google for garbage URLs. I can't figure out where they are coming from. Here is a sample of a few. These URIs exist no where in the site structure so I am assuming they are being created by an external  agent/site that is driving Gbot to crawl them. Anyone have any ideas?

> 7/2/2013 22:05    /Sl/4watQCXBFtF6obwFRA0f35148b  10262   404 - Not Found No
>   Referrer  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;
>   +http://www.google.com/bot.html)
>
> 7/2/2013 22:05    /PvDIs6AveH9tju3tETtWg045cb22d  10261   404 - Not Found No
>   Referrer  Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1;
>   +http://www.google.com/bot.html)